# multiple active network connections in windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, ssh

My phone is a Nokia-N900, and I find the most useful way to interact with it from my PC is by ssh. Luckily it is possible to switch out the usb-networking module in the devices kernel to make it appear to windows as a generic RNDIS gadget. Plugging it into a windows PC I can now ssh into it, I can open an sftp session, everything works perfectly...

Except I can't access the web. I can't view other network resources. I look in the network connections section in the control panel and see my two connections, but I don't see any way to set which one to use for what. Seeing as I only use usb0 for ssh and eth0 for everything else, it seems I need a way to set it up so that usb0 only gets port 22 or something similar.

Is there any way to achieve this, or another method by which I could leave my phone connected to my Pc while using it for other network tasks?

Comment: Are you trying to access the external Internet via the computer or via the phone while you are `ssh`ed into it?

Comment: via the computer - the phone has no trouble using its own 3g or wifi connections rather than attempting to use the usb connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the following [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/89456).

---

Info added by OP:

As explained in the linked article, you can set the *interface metric* for each network interface, with the lower numbered interfaces taking priority. I found that after setting the usb interface to have a priority of 100 (usually a very slow interface would be set to 50) my device was able to be connected to via ssh over usb, and I am still able to connect to everything else from my computer.